# What are charted collections in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I'm watching an official mongo aggregation framework tutorial and it mentions that "$geoNear can be used on '*charted collections*' where $near can't" ([source](https://youtu.be/N-sXnY_tfYU?t=33)). I have no idea what a *charted collection* is and googling "charted collections mongodb" gives no results.

Comment: I'm guessing you misheard "sharded collections"

Comment: lol, @martin-smith you are right. I got confused because the official subtitles say 'charted'.